# Django ImageField url slow when using Amazon s3

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, boto

In my Django Application currently running on Heroku I noticed that retrieving url's from ImageFields takes forever when hosting on s3.
The application is written using Django Rest Framework. When I try to retrieve a list of objects that have image fields the response is so slow Heroku throws a timeout error. I assume this is because boto has to retrieve a url from s3 for each individual ImageField upon each request.
How can I speed up the process to prevent these timeout errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new field in your models, for example, `image_url`.

```
class YourModel(...):
    image_url = models.CharField(...)
    # other fields
```

When the image is uploaded/saved the first time, retrieve its URL and populate `image_url` field with this value. You'll need to save your model again, though.

You can use this value later when required.

**Demerits**

This may lead to unnecessary database lookups. If, however, you use Memcached or something like that to cache database, I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 1):

One of solution was provided by xyers above. Here is other possible solution I used for my project.
You can define the MEDIA_URL variable in settings.py file of your django project:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Then you can use this variable when you need to access to URL. For example if you have model:

```
class MyModel(...):
    image = FileField(...)
```

Then you can get URL of that file as follows:

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(...)
image_url = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, mymodel.image.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced similar problem, what I decided to do is to change this:

```
class SomeModelSerilazier(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    png_icon = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

    def get_png_icon(self, some_model_obj):
        return some_model_obj.png_icon.url
```

to this:

```
    def get_png_icon(self, some_model_obj):
        return str(some_model_obj.png_icon)
```

surprisingly, its working ~ 15 times faster on my machine.